# php - incorrect charset of og data from website

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8

I use `cur`l to read content from https://www.thegioididong.com/dtdd/iphone-6 then use DOM to parse the og metadata but the data is incorrect encoding, but when debug with facebook og debugger, the result is correct https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/

here is my description meta result:

> iPhone 6 ra máº¯t vá»i sá»± thay Äá»i lá»n vá» máº·t thiáº¿t káº¿ vÃ  cáº¥u hÃ¬nh so vá»i cÃ¡c tháº¿ há» trÆ°á»c. iPhone 6 cÃ³ mÃ n hÃ¬nh lá»n Äáº¿n 4,7 inch vÃ  Camera chá»ng rung quang há»c.*

Result from facebook:

> iPhone 6 ra mắt với sự thay đổi lớn về mặt thiết kế và cấu hình so với các thế hệ trước. iPhone 6 có màn hình lớn đến 4,7 inch và Camera chống rung quang học.*

I've tried to convert text to `UTF-8` but still not work, here is the code

```
iconv(mb_detect_encoding($text, mb_detect_order(), true), "UTF-8", $text);
```

I also tried `file_get_contents` instead of `curl` but still get the same result. Could anyone figure out how? Many thanks.

---

**SOLVED:**

I figured out the problem: convert html content before use DOM to parse content

```
mb_convert_encoding($content, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8')
```

Comment: Better to post the above "answer comment" as an Answer or an Edit to the question if it solved the problem for future readers

Comment: thanks Mi-Creatitivy

Comment: You welcome, don't forget to post that comment as an answer to your own question!